# Program unable to launch when working with frames

Tags: java

I have the below code,

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class MyFrame
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation
        (
            JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
        );
    }
}
```

However when I 'Run' in Eclipse, it throws me an error that the selection could not be run. Im new to java, so Im not sure what's happening.

I tried to change the main class in Run Configurations, and I set it to MyFrame, however it's telling me that it can't find that class.

Image of my IDE: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzbp4.png)

Comment: Post the full error message please

Comment: what is the name of your file? does it `MyFrame.java`

Comment: That exact code works as expected in the IDE I have on-screen..

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class MyFrame`

Comment: I even went to https://www.onlinegdb.com/ and got the same error. Perhaps a configuration issue

Comment: As @YCF_L asks, what is the name of your file?

Comment: The name of my file is `frame.java`

Comment: @legoMyEgo the name should match the public class's name.

Comment: Well there you go. The file name should match the class name.

Comment: Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Thank you, everyone